# Most popular PHP proxy scripts

Tags: php, proxy

I need to write a proxy script to log into secure servers without ever revealing an administrative password.

Can someone recommend some proxy scripts (written in PHP preferably) that I can look into?

Thanks!

Edit: I would be most interested in well documented scripts... if that matters.

Comment: Can you explain better what these "proxy scripts" are?

Comment: By "proxy script" I mean a PHP application/script that I can send a URL and have it act as a proxy for that URL.  Sort of like http://worldproxyit.com/worldproxy/phproxy/index.php but it doesn't need to display the content.

Comment: See the PHP manual page for `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get this package,

http://anonproxyserver.sourceforge.net/

There are several simple proxy scripts in PHP. For example proxy_server.php.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this script: https://github.com/4dboard/Proxy-yxorP

Web  Proxy (GUI) : The SAAS(y), Multi-tenancy, Headless, Plug & Play, Web Proxy, Guzzler - Back-end included, PHP CURL+Composer are Optional. Leveraging SAAS architecture to provide multi-tenancy, multiple threads, caching, and an article spinner service.

It is a new script using modern code to create a very fast and powerful web proxy script, and it includes an admin GUI.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32325398)